# String comparison in Tkinter

Tags: python, string, tkinter

I'm trying to write simple GUI that will generate numbers, write them to the string, and after pressing "Check" button it will compare the input from the user with generated numbers.In this code function `print(x==y)` should print me TRUE, since i provide the same numbers which were generated, but it prints me FALSE.What is the problem? Could you help me please?

```
from tkinter import*
from random import randint

def compare():
    global string2
    global string1

    string2=str(string2.get())
    print (string1 == string2)




def generate():
    global k
    number.config(text=string1[k])
    k=k+1
    number.after(2000, remove) 

def remove():
    global repeat

    number.config(text='')

    repeat -= 1
    if repeat > 0:
        number.after(1000, generate) 



root = Tk()

i=3
k=0
j=0
repeat = i
string1=str()
string2=StringVar()

while j < i:
    string1=string1+str(randint(1,10))
    j=j+1



number = Label(root, width=20, height=10)
number.pack()

ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
ent.pack()

but = Button(text="Check",command = compare)
but.pack()


generate()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `print()` to display `x` and `y`. and use `print(type(...))` to see types - maybe you compare string with integer.

Comment: btw: instead of `x=str()` you can use `x = ""`

Comment: I ran the code and added print statements to see what the values were, and the reason it's printing False for if they're equal, is because they're not equal. As a side note, it makes it a lot easier to follow your code if you give your variables meaningful names. single letter names are almost never a good idea when they represent more than a loop counter.

Comment: i checked their types an it prints me `<class 'str'>` for both of them

Comment: Make sure to also print their values, for me x was 600 and something and y was 6. When the number on screen was 6, so there's some error in terms of x

Comment: did you check values in `x` and `y` ? I found that program generate 4-digits number but it shows only three so I always put wrong number.

Comment: i also checked their values, sometimes they equal but sometimes they not, i dont understand why is that

Comment: proble is `randint(1,10)` which can give `10` so you number can have 3 or 4-digits. Or if it gives `10` three times then you get even `101010`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is `ranint(1,10)` which can give values `1...10`,not `1...9`.
  So finally it generates 4-digits number instead of 3-digits one.
(but it could generate even 6-digits number `"101010"` - `"10" + "10" + "10"`)

Use `randint(1, 9)` or `randrange(1, 10)`

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

# --- functions ---

def compare():
    print(number_str == answer.get())

def generate():
    global index

    lab.config(text=number_str[index])

    index += 1

    root.after(2000, remove) 

def remove():
    global repeat

    lab.config(text='')

    repeat -= 1
    if repeat > 0:
        root.after(1000, generate) 

# --- main ---

number_of_digits = 3
repeat = number_of_digits

index = 0

number_str = ""

for _ in range(number_of_digits):
    number_str = number_str + str(randint(1,9))

#print(number_str)

root = tk.Tk()

answer = tk.StringVar()

lab = tk.Label(root, width=20, height=10)
lab.pack()

ent = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=answer, width=20, bd=3)
ent.pack()

but = tk.Button(text="Check", command=compare)
but.pack()

generate()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @furas!